# Debugging MobileServiceClient request

Tags: javascript, azure, asp.net-web-api, xmlhttprequest, asp.net-web-api2

I'm developing an Azure MobileService / CordovaApp setup. The server runs locally and has the following setting to enable CORS:

```
<add name="Access-Control-Allow-Origin" value="*" />
```

The api can be called via browser using addresses like

```
http://localhost:59477/api/item/explore/A/B
```

The client script that's trying to depict this call is the following:

```
var client = new WindowsAzure.MobileServiceClient('http://localhost:59477/', 'http://localhost:59477/', '');
GetItems.addEventListener("click",
function ()
{
    client.invokeApi("item/explore/A/B",
        {
            method: "get"
        })
        .done(
        function (results)
        {
            alert(results.result.count);
        },
        function (error)
        {
            var xhr = error.request;
            alert('Error - status code: ' + xhr.status + '; body: ' + xhr.responseText);
            alert(error.message);
        }
    );
}
);
```

What I get is status 405 - Method not allowed, which I don't understand for two reasons:

- The invoked Service Action is decorated with the [HttpGet] Attribute
- The response headers seem to say GET is fine:

```
    HTTP/1.1 405 Method Not Allowed
    Allow: GET
    Content-Length: 76
    Content-Type: application/json; charset=utf-8
    Server: Microsoft-IIS/8.0
    X-SourceFiles: =?UTF-8?B?RjpcQ29kZVxGb290UHJpbnRzXGZvb3RwcmludHMuU2VydmVyXEZvb3RwcmludHNTZXJ2aWNlXGFwaVxmb290cHJpbnRcZXhwbG9yZVw1MS4yNzcwMjJcNy4wNDA3ODM=?=
    X-Powered-By: ASP.NET
    Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *
    Date: Sat, 15 Aug 2015 18:08:30 GMT
```

Any idea what I can do to get this running?

---

**Edit**
The Raw request shows that, as already expected by Jeremy Foster, the client sends a request of the type OPTIONS:

```
OPTIONS http://localhost:59477/api/fp/get?id=1 HTTP/1.1
Host: localhost:59477
Connection: keep-alive
Access-Control-Request-Method: GET
Origin: http://localhost:4400
User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; WOW64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/44.0.2403.155 Safari/537.36
Access-Control-Request-Headers: accept, x-zumo-features, x-zumo-installation-id, x-zumo-version
Accept: */*
Referer: http://localhost:4400/index.html
Accept-Encoding: gzip, deflate, sdch
Accept-Language: de-DE,de;q=0.8,en-US;q=0.6,en;q=0.4
```

I managed to support this request applying the `[HttpOptions]` attribute to my action method. Now I get a more or less valid response:

```
HTTP/1.1 200 OK
Content-Type: text/html; charset=utf-8
Content-Encoding: gzip
Vary: Accept-Encoding
Server: Microsoft-IIS/8.0
X-SourceFiles: =?UTF-8?B?RjpcQ29kZVxGb290UHJpbnRzXGZvb3RwcmludHMuU2VydmVyXEZvb3RwcmludHNTZXJ2aWNlXGFwaVxmcFxnZXRcMQ==?=
X-Powered-By: ASP.NET
Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *
Access-Control-Allow-Headers: Origin, X-Requested-With, Content-Type, Accept
Date: Sun, 23 Aug 2015 19:34:21 GMT
Content-Length: 234

         ...
```

At least that's what fiddler tells me. The AzureMobileServiceClient throws yet another issue, which roughly translates as:

```
Cross-Origin request blocked, missing token 'x-zumo-installation-id' in CORS header row 'Access-Control-Allow-Headers' on CORS-Preflight-Channel
```

Comment: I'm not sure it's wrong behavior for the client to issue an OPTIONS request. I'm guessing it's intended actually. It may be that an error response from an OPTIONS request is preferable to a failed GET request, so the client issues an OPTIONS first as a sort of "ping". Just a guess. Can't find anything in the documentation (which makes me suspect). I'm checking with some folks.

Answer (score 2):

Turn on [Fiddler](http://www.telerik.com/fiddler) and try your api call from the browser and then again using the Mobile Services client and compare your raw HTTP requests to see what's different.

Comment: Thanks for pointing me at fiddler. The detailed error message is: `message=The requested resource does not support http method 'OPTIONS'`.

Comment: I have tried and tested many ideas found on the web now, but none of them seems to work. As far as I understand, the missing OPTIONS method should not be a show-stopper for the request I intend to send, but in fact it is...

Comment: Hmm. It's not that there's a missing OPTIONS method, but rather that the Mobile Services client is choosing to send an HTTP request that is an HTTP OPTIONS (as opposed to a GET or POST or something). Not sure why. Can you post the raw HTTP request that results in that error? Fiddler will tell you that.

Comment: Damn it Jeremy, you were right - please see the edited original Post. Any idea what can cause this?

Comment: What happens if you publish the Mobile Service to Azure and then point your client there?

Comment: Please view my Edits, I added the HTTPOptions Attribute to my action and get another CORS-related error message, which concerns X-ZUMO-INSTALLATION-ID...

Comment: You're on to something. Looks like the OPTIONS request happens because of CORS. It's a "pre-flight" request. The next error about the installation-id might be answered by [this](https://visualstudiomagazine.com/articles/2012/09/24/win-azure-mobile/listing1.aspx). Try simply adding the x-zumo-installation-id header as a guid.

Comment: Thanks, Jeremy! Will try that later!

Answer (score 1):

Try to run through the **CORS Support** section of this blog post: http://azure.microsoft.com/blog/2014/07/28/azure-mobile-services-net-updates/.

A side note: The x-zumo-installation-id error you were getting was because the client requested access for a list of headers (see the `Access-Control-Request-Headers` in your request) and the server did not return that same list in the `Access-Control-Allow-Headers` header. Using the `MS_CrossDomainOrigins` setting as mentioned in the above blog post takes care of this by setting the allowed headers to `*` (all) by default.